# JavaScript date returns wrong month if day is 01

Tags: javascript, date

I am trying to get correct month from the date string, this works fine as long as the day isn't the first of the month (`01`). If the day is the first, it returns the previous month:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<p>Click the button to display the month.</p>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var str="2014-12-01"
    var d = new Date(str); 
    var m = d.getMonth()+1;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = m;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Returns: `11`
Should return: `12`

If the date string was `2013-8-01` then `7` would be returned, when it should be `8`. Without the `+1` after the `getMonth()` then `6` would be returned, instead of `7`.

Comment: The date string is parsed as UTC, so if you are in a time zone west of Greenwich, the date will be the previous day. For those with a positive offset, it works just fine. :-)

Answer (score 10):

The actual problem lies within the timezone of your computer.

Suppose that your computer is in [Eastern Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eastern_Time_Zone) (GMT-5):

```
var foo = new Date('2014-12-01');

foo.toUTCString(); // "Mon, 01 Dec 2014 00:00:00 GMT"
foo.toISOString(); // "2014-12-01T00:00:00.000Z"
foo.toString(); // "Sun Nov 30 2014 19:00:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)"
```

Notice that the date is actually in November because it's a few hours behind, and therefore the zero-indexed month would be 10. JavaScript automatically assumes UTC when you do not provide a time string.

> The [`getMonth()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getMonth) method returns the month in the specified date according to local time, as a zero-based value (where zero indicates the first month of the year.

In local time, this Date object represents November 30 at 19h00 (7pm), so `getMonth()` returns 10:

```
foo.getMonth(); // 10
foo.getUTCMonth(); // 11
```

If you are not concerned about time zones and are just dealing with dates, perhaps look into using the `getUTC*` methods.

[You can read more about the `Date` object here.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) Hope this helps.

Comment: **The getMonth() method returns the month in the specified date according to local time, as a zero-based value (where zero indicates the first month of the year).** and **The value returned by getUTCMonth is an integer between 0 and 11 corresponding to the month. 0 for January, 1 for February, 2 for March, and so on.**

Comment: Which is exactly what is happening. In local time, the month is still November, so it returns 10.

Comment: I had this exact issue. However, I was already using getUTCMonth() which was returning the previous month for the first day of each month. Switching this to getMonth() fixed the issue and returned the correct month.

One possible reason why my issue was fixed the other way round was because I was using pre-xisting epoch timestamps which were likely generated at a local time that is 4/5 hours behind my local time.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript is doing what it should do. In the day value it interprets the `01` as `0`, and a zero value for the day is interpreted as the last day of the previous month. It's like asking for day 32 in a month with 31 days. That would return a date of the first of the next month.

Comment: you are wrong!!! `var str="2014-12-18"; var d = new Date(str); var m = d.getMonth(); // <- 11 `

Comment: Come to think of it, the OP's date format is incorrect to start with. It should be `var str="2014,12,1"`

Comment: `var str="2014-12-18"; var d = new Date(str); alert(d); // <- Thu Dec 18 2014 04:00:00 GMT+0400` Evertything is ok with his code

Comment: `var str="2014-12-1"; var d = new Date(str); alert(d) // Invalid date` 
`

Comment: This answer is incorrect. See rink.attendant.6's answer.

Answer (score 0):

getMonth() returns a value from 0 to 11: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_getmonth.asp
January is 0, February is 1, and so on.

So to get the 'right' month, you should do +1.

Comment: That is not the issue. See rink.attendant.6's answer.