# Javascript date is incorrect from int value

Tags: javascript

```js
var vdate= new Date(parseInt("1438405200000"));
var vmonth = vdate.getMonth() + 1;
alert(vmonth);
```

When I create a date variable in javascript from int value I get incorrect month, 
In the example the date(1438405200000) is 2015-08-01

```
var vdate= new Date(parseInt("1438405200000"));
var vmonth = vdate.getMonth() + 1;
alert(vmonth);
```

Alert shows 7, the correct is 8, this occurs only in some PC.Can be regional setting or something like that?

Comment: Months are zero indexed.

Comment: Use `parseInt("1438405200000", 10)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript date returns wrong Month if day is 01](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25288781/javascript-date-returns-wrong-month-if-day-is-01)

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this is because Months are `0-11`, not `1-12`. (Think of it as elements in an array. `var months = ["January", "February", "March"...]`)

[MDN Docs on `Date.prototype.getMonth()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getMonth)

In addition, you're likely in a timezone more than 5 hours behind GMT. (Since that timestamp specifically corresponds to 05:00:00 on the first of August, 2015) JavaScript's date object will attempt to localize times to your current timezone. (In my case, `GMT-7`) So, using `getMonth()` for me will return `6` rather than `7`. If localization is the desired behavior, then this is fine. Otherwise, if it's a UTC time, and you want to get the specific UTC representation, you should call `getUTCMonth()` instead, or otherwise compensate for the timezone offset.

Comment: getUTCMonth() is the solution, the website has user from different timezones