# issue with getting the month number on the first day of the month

Tags: javascript

I am trying to solve an issue where JS is returning the previous month number if I input a date like "2023-01-01" or "2023-02-01" it returns the previous month number. For the first case, it returns month number of 11 but it should be 0. In the second case it returns 0 whereas it should be 1. If i select a date such as "2023-01-02", the correct month number is returned 0.
I am debugging using the console like so:

```js
const date = "2023-01-01";
console.log(date)
console.log(new Date(date).getMonth())
```

and using a html input for setting the date variable.
Anyidea why this is happening and how it can be solved?

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. I get 0. Can you provide more context?

Comment: This sounds like a timezone issue. It's parsing the input in GMT, but your timezone is behind GMT.

Comment: @jabaa What timezone are you in? I get `11` in US/Eastern.

Comment: @Barmar I'm in UTC+2

Comment: duplicate: [JavaScript date returns wrong month if day is 01](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25288781/javascript-date-returns-wrong-month-if-day-is-01)

Comment: Of course you could just `Number('2023-01-01'.slice(5, 7))` (`-1` if you need the zero based value)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`getMonth`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getMonth) is using your local browser timezone. If your local timezone happens to be west of UTC+0, you'll get the prior local month in the first hour of the UTC month.  Use [`getUTCMonth`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getUTCMonth) instead.

```js
const date = "2023-01-01";
console.log(date)
console.log(new Date(date).getUTCMonth())
```

Comment: The never ending joy of timezones